# div block going to next line in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `display:block`  in my css. This div block uses the `align = "absmiddle"` . It displays all the elements in 1 line in Chrome. However, in firefox, the elements are displyed on to the next line as well. How do I get them to display in 1 single line in firefox.

P.S: I have already tried `display: inline` but it does not bring it in 1 line.

```
<div class="one"><input name="elementone" value="1" align="absmiddle" class="subone" /></div>
```

Css is

```
div.one,div.subone{
display:block; 
width:16px; 
height:100%;
background-position:0 0px;
border:0
}
```

Comment: This looks okay here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/cU9xu/

Comment: But if i am getting it on a second line in firefox, is there anything I can do to get it all on 1 single line?

Comment: I am using Firefox too (4b11) what version of FF are you using, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: the code you posted above is correct and both chrome and firefox display the div correctly, so please edit your answer with more detail

Comment: Div tags have display:block by default. Why are you even setting that explicitly? If you actually **had** to do that, then I'd look around to see if some other style rule isn't filtering down here.

Comment: absmiddle is a non-standard value for align property. Rather use one of css vertical-align values - top, bottom, middle, baseline.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to accomplish - centering input elements in a div?

All you need is a text-align: center on container div that holds all the inputs [.one is the class that should have center text alignment in the case of your example html].

Note there are some issues with your css

```
div.one,div.subone{ /*div.subone refers to a div with the class subone - not an input like you have*/
display:block; /*divs are already block elements */
width:16px;  /* may be the issue, why restrict the width? */
height:100%; /*basically meaningless */
background-position:0 0px; /*default*/
border:0
}
```

***Note: generally when you are trying to wrap a bunch of inline elements like inputs each inside their own div, there is another way to skin that cat.  For instance, in this case if you have a number of divs with the class .one - they will show up on their own line because your css requires each div to display block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but if you want multiple `<div class="one">` in one line just float them left or right. However they will still jump to second line once the container div width is exceded. You could try and use a combination of white-space and overflow on the parent div.

But as I say - your problem is quite unclear from the question.